# How do I set a selection of properties in DevExpress (Winforms) custom skin?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

We're using a custom skin throughout our application. Recently, some folks here decided they don't like the way the groupcontrol looks. By bolding the caption and setting the groupControl's LookAndFeel.UseWindowsXPTheme = true, though, I make them happy.

Is there any way to set these properties in the skin (or elsewhere) so we developers don't need to manually set the group box control every time we use it? I loaded up our skin.xml file in the skin editor but nothing in that gui seemed obvious to me. From the documentation I've read, it sounds as though I need to make the changes on a pixel-by-pixel basis, more or less.

Having these properties set at design time would be nice.

We have a fair amount (dozens?) of groupControls already out there, so going back and modifying these two properties would be something of a pain.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to set these properties at design time.

Comment: I could create a child class of the GroupControl and set that property to true, which would work at design time. I would prefer not go through all the instances of GroupControl and update them at this point, though. Something like this would work: 

public class MyGroupControl : GroupControl
    {
        public MyGroupControl()
        {
            base.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
            base.LookAndFeel.UseWindowsXPTheme = true;
        }
    }